# Collection View won't show images

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I've set up a Collection View in my storyboard and set its delegate and data source to the view controller, put an ImageView inside of a cell, and have even changed the background of it, but I can't get it to show an image. I've tried adding a button to reload the data, but when I click it nothing happens so I don't think the image is even being passed.

I made sure that my cell and image view has an identifier and I'm using the following code to try to populate the collection view:

View.h file:

```
 __weak IBOutlet UICollectionView *CollectionView;
```

View.m file

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 1;

}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:302];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sunset.jpeg"];
[imageView setImage:image];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you set the CollectionViewCell tag value to 302?

Comment: try this way to set image `cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sunset.jpeg"];` and set imageview outlet @Nil2k15